# IPFS IONIC iOS: How remove lock file in datastore-level?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, locking, ipfs, levelup

I have nodejs running in iOS which has IPFS. After 1 run, the app crashes or something happens. IPFS has datastore-level, which leaves its LOCK file behind. How do you cleanup such lock files in mobile apps, sp. iOS?

```
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/20D2439A-C8ED-4417-940F-60287CB4CD60/dapp4.app/www/nodejs-project/node_modules/datastore-level/src/index.js:49
          throw err
          ^

OpenError: IO error: lock /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CB4F4342-0932-4945-9A8C-707FC84A1FE0/tmp/js2ipfs/datastore/LOCK: already held by process
```